# Need to change my database Connection from Sandbox to newly deployed cluster(1gb plan) in Mlab for parse hosted in Heroku?

Tags: android, heroku, parse-platform, mlab

I am working on an Android APP which uses Parse as a backend hosted in Heroku Server with Mlab as a database(using Sandbox plan). 
Now I am unable to upload any image to my parse dashboard, I checked everything with parse dashboard and app it works fine.It seems the Sandbox free limit is over, So i purchased a 1 gb plan.But i am unable to connect to the new cluster plan(1gb plan).
How can i connect my app to the new 1gb cluster plan, and move from Sandbox plan?

I have already taken a backup from sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for moving from an mLab Sandbox database to a mLab Cluster plan can be found here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#changing-plans

Also, we provide timely, expert support for all plans. Please feel free to reach out to support@mlab.com for any questions you may have.

Disclosure: I work for mLab.